# Camel: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: No component found with scheme

Tags: apache-camel

I have a custom Camel component packaged in a separate jar. As advised here:

```
http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-add-a-component.html
```

I created a file a META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/component/aq (aq is the component scheme name) containing:

```
class=<full class name>
```

Everything works When I run a test program standalone. However, when I try deploying it into a container (servicemix, karaf) it cannot resolve the component scheme name:

```
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route7: Route(route7)[[From[aq:oprDequeuer]] -> [WireTap[properties:... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: aq://queue1 due to: No component found with scheme: aq
```

Also, when I register the component explicitly:

```
    CamelContext context = getContext();
    context.addComponent("aq", new AQComponent(context));
```

it works fine, including ServiceMix.

Comment: How did you deploy the component? Can you check if your route is loaded after the bundle is started.

Comment: The route works fine as long as I explicitly reference the deployed component as above.

Comment: Does your component bundle have the osgi export service head org.apache.camel.spi.ComponentResolver;component=aq just as other camel components does?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that file in META-INF is included in the JAR.

If that file is missing then the component cannot be auto discovered, and that is your problem. As you build a component for OSGi, then maybe the felix bundle plugin somehow does not include that file.

I suggest to double check this, and look inside the built JAR if the file is included.

Comment: Yup, the META-INF directory is bundled with the jar with all the files in it.